# Jekyll Pagination Index not found

Tags: pagination, jekyll

First off, I am using Jekyll 3.5.1

I have enabled Pagination in my Jekyll config and have added the following to my _config.yml file:

```
 #pagination
 paginate: 5
 paginate_path: "blog/page:num"
```

In my root directory, I have created a folder called 'blog' with inside of it an 'index.html' file. Yet, when I try to serve the file I get the warning that pagination can not find an index.html file.

I have also tried to just use the index.html file under root, but that was unsuccesfull as well.

Here you can see the [github repo](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/blog/tree/pagination/jekyll) in case that would be of any help.

I have tried to play with the paginate_path as well as with the index.html file. Any help would be appreciated!

The concrete error message is:

```
Pagination: Pagination is enabled, but I couldn't find an index.html page to use as the pagination template. Skipping pagination.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

`index.html` must not be empty. The pagination template file (as referred by `pagination_path` should contain the code to generate each page with the list of posts, as [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/) suggests, create `blog/index.html`:

```
---
layout: default
title: My Blog
---

<!-- This loops through the paginated posts -->
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
  <h1><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
  <p class="author">
    <span class="date">{{ post.date }}</span>
  </p>
  <div class="content">
    {{ post.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}

<!-- Pagination links -->
<div class="pagination">
  {% if paginator.previous_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path }}" class="previous">Previous</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="previous">Previous</span>
  {% endif %}
  <span class="page_number ">Page: {{ paginator.page }} of {{ paginator.total_pages }}</span>
  {% if paginator.next_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path }}" class="next">Next</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="next ">Next</span>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: i have this done, problems insists.

Comment: @Nitwit What is the output of`{{paginator}}` or `{{paginator.posts}}` ?

Answer (score -1):

One cause of this error message: The Brackets Editor 'Beautifier' command doesn't recognize YAML code when it executes, so it sees the top YAML of your index.html file:

```
---
layout: default
title: Jekyll Title
---
```

... and transforms the 4 lines into one continuous line:

```
--- layout: default  title: Jekyll Themes ---
```

Jekyll responds with the error message:

> Pagination: Pagination is enabled, but I couldn't find an index.html page to use as the pagination template. Skipping pagination."